# Remove the Product Image block and replace it with HTML Code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

how can we insert a Product Image on a wordpress website using HTML rather than uploading an Imagine. The official product image not simply inserting an image in the description.

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1. Create a new theme or child theme; 2. Custom the template file as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an image in description using `<img>` tag. Here is the full lesson on this tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp